# Is it possible to use Jenkins for Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, jenkins, flutter, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to create pipeline for build release to play store using Jenkins with Flutter? I need to build a release for production/dev to play store.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, the easiest way to do this is to use a tool like [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) that integrates with Jenkins. I have used Fastlane myself and it's just incredible the amount of time it can save. It has an amazing CLI that can scaffold a deploy for you.

It has integrations with Jenkins https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/jenkins/

Example **Fastfile** file:

```
  private_lane :push_test_flight do
    sync_code_signing # Handles certificates

    increment_build_number(
      build_number: "1.2.5"
    )

    increment_version_number(
      version_number: "1.0.0"
    )

    build_app(workspace: ENV["WORKSPACE"], scheme: "Example App")

    upload_to_testflight(
      reject_build_waiting_for_review: true,
      demo_account_required: true,
      beta_app_feedback_email: "some@mail-o.co",
      beta_app_description: "A proof of concept app",
      notify_external_testers: false,
      changelog: "POC Updates",
      beta_app_review_info: {
        contact_email: "some@mail-o.co",
        contact_first_name: "Some",
        contact_last_name: "Mail",
        contact_phone: "5558675309",
        demo_account_name: "demo@mail.com",
        demo_account_password: "demo@mail",
        notes: "A proof of concept app"
      },
    )
  end
```

This will manage my iOS distribution certificates, build the app with XCode and then push to testFlight!

Comment: @c-ogoo what about this two article? but they didn't use fastlane. for ios https://www.raywenderlich.com/1774995-continuous-integration-with-github-fastlane-jenkins for android https://medium.com/mindorks/automating-android-app-play-store-publishing-via-jenkins-a6c30dbc59dd

Comment: The first article for iOS uses Fastlane. The second article for android doesn't but you can achieve the same a lot easier with fastlane (and a lot less code). Ive updated the wording of my answer.